# Can I combine these two docker images?

Tags: .net, docker

I'm new to docker so this might be the wrong way to achieve this.

When I create a new .net project in visual studio and say I want it to run on docker, it creates this docker file.

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build 

or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

I want to use Azure table storage in my application, which has this image already created

microsoft/azure-storage-emulator as tableStorage

Can I add

```
FROM microsoft/azure-storage-emulator as tableStorage
```

in the same Dockerfile and use the Table Storage emulator on the same continer image somehow? Clearly they seem to be combining a bunch of images, but I cannot figure out how to combine the table storage image.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking at a multi-stage build. It does not combine images together, it builds multiple images and allows copying files between them.

Comment: aye aye captain!